# Perché da crusta è derivato cròsta (o aperta) e non crósta (o chiusa)?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

La parola italiana *crosta* deriva, stando al mio Devoto-Oli, dal latino *crusta*. Dato che in latino c'è una *u*, io mi aspetterei, per paragone con tante altre parole, una *o* chiusa, dunque crósta. Invece il Devoto-Oli scrive sillaba crò.sta, dicendo dunque che quella *o* è aperta. Esistono altri casi di *u* diventate *o* aperte in italiano? E come mai (se è noto) si trovano queste eccezioni? O sono io che mi sono inventato la regola u breve > o chiusa che in realtà non esiste?

Comment: Vedi http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=76046&r=1926

Comment: Cos'è "docentate"? E "Latinu" sarebbe "latino"?

Comment: @Charo scherzi del cellulare :). Fixed.

Comment: Per quel che vale, io dico *crósta* (con la *ó* chiusa) e credo sia la pronuncia più comune (possibilmente al di fuori dal centro Italia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il [Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronuncia della RAI](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=76046&r=1926) spiega che la pronuncia originaria di "crosta" era con la "o" chiusa derivata dalla "u" breve del latino "crusta". Questa pronuncia con la "o" chiusa si conserva ancora nell'Italia settentrionale e in qualche altra regione, ma è scomparsa o quasi in Toscana e nell'Italia centrale, dov'è mutata in "o" aperta.

Secondo questo stesso [dizionario](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=72972&r=208) un fenomeno simile è accaduto al termine "colonna": la pronuncia originaria con "o" chiusa derivata dalla "u" breve del latino "columna" si mantiene in Toscana, ma è mutata in "o" aperta nelle altre regioni italiane.

Comment: Vorrei ricordare, per completezza, che l'uso toscano – piaccia o no – è quello che, per così dire fa testo, cioè quello a cui si conforma l'italiano standard.

Comment: @DaG:  Tuttavia, nel libro *Italiano grammatica. Grammatica essenziale della lingua italiana* di Melina Insolera, pubblicato da Zanichelli, si afferma: «Lo straniero che studia l'italiano deve essere preparato a uno sforzo supplementare, proprio perché l'italiano, mentre ha uno standard scritto altamente codificato, manca concretamente di uno standard per il parlato, nel quale si riflettono di necessità  le molte differenti pronunce regionali».